# AngularJS on top of server generated content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm looking for a way to integrate something like `ng-repeat` with static content. That is, to send static divs and to have them bound to JS array (or rather, to have an array constructed from content and *then* bound to it).

I realize that I could send static content, then remove and regenerate the dynamic bits. I'd like not to write the same divs twice though.

The goal is not only to cater for search engines and people without js, but to strike a healthy balance between static websites and single page applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you meant, but it was interesting enough to try.

Basically what this directive does is create an item for each of its children by collecting the properties that were bound with `ng-bind`. And after it's done that it leaves just the first child as a template for `ng-repeat`.

Directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('unrepeat', function($parse) {
    return {
        compile : function (element, attrs) {

            /* get name of array and item from unrepeat-attribute */
            var arrays = $parse(attrs.unrepeat)();
            angular.forEach(arrays, function(v,i){
                this[i] = [];

                /* get items from divs */
                angular.forEach(element.children(), function(el){
                    var item = {}

                    /* find the bound properties, and put text values on item */
                    $(el).find('[ng-bind^="'+v+'."]').each(function(){
                        var prop = $(this).attr('ng-bind').split('.');

                         /* ignoring for the moment complex properties like item.prop.subprop */
                        item[prop[1]] = $(this).text();
                    });
                    this[i].push(item);
                });
            });

            /* remove all children except first */
            $(element).children(':gt(0)').remove()

            /* add array to scope in postLink, when we have a scope to add it to*/
            return  function postLink(scope) {
                angular.forEach(arrays, function(v,i){
                    scope[i] = this[i];
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Usage example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div unrepeat="{list:'item'}" >
        <div ng-repeat="item in list">
            <span ng-bind="item.name">foo</span>
            <span ng-bind="item.value">bar</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in list">
            <span ng-bind="item.name">spam</span>
            <span ng-bind="item.value">eggs</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in list">
            <span ng-bind="item.name">cookies</span>
            <span ng-bind="item.value">milk</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="list.push({name:'piep', value:'bla'})">Add</button>
</div>
```

Presumable those repeated `divs` are created in a loop by PHP or some other backend application, hence why I put `ng-repeat` in all of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/LvjyZ/

(Note that there is some superfluous use of $(), because I didn't load jQuery and Angular in the right order, and the `.find` on angular's jqLite lacks some features.)

Answer (score 0):

You really have only one choice for this:

- Render differently for search engines on the server, using something like [the approach described here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)

The problem is you would need to basically rewrite all the directives to support loading their data from DOM, and then loading their templates somehow without having them show up in the DOM as well.

As an alternative, you could investigate using [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) instead of Angular, which (at least according to their website) could be used to render things directly on the web server without using a heavy setup like phantomjs.

Comment: That solves the problem of SEO, but the problem I am more interested in is that the separation of static and dynamic content is too rigid.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė unless you want to rewrite all the directives, then this is the only way. towr's example is pretty much the other option you'd have, and you'd need to do that for all other directives you use as well (though the issue isn't as big with directives that don't replace stuff like ng-repeat)